# structuring things in XML file

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization

I want to have something below to save in the xml file

```
Question0 : What is ur name?
 Answer0: Tina
   Question0.0 : What are your hobbies?
           Answer0.0.0 : reading 
               Question0.0.0.0 :What do you like in reading.?
                      Answer0.. : .....
           Answer0.0.1 : Dancing
               Question0.0.0.1 :which dance do you like?

 Answer1:Roger 
   ...........same question answer as above.
```

There can be nested question below an answer but below a question there can only be answers.

What will be the proper way to write into xml suing java. I can't think of a way....? Step by step solution to me will be great as I am new to java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use JAXB.

It consists in writing JavaBeans holding the information (in your case, a `Question` and an `Answer` class, with the Question class holding a list of answers, and the answer class holding a (sub-)question).

Then, you ave to annotate the classes to tell JAXB how to map the JavaBean properties to XML attributes or elements.

And then you have to get a Marshaller which will transform your JavaBean tree into an XML document.

The following page has a short tutorial over these steps. Googling for JAXB will lead you to a more exhaustive documentation: http://www.vogella.de/articles/JAXB/article.html#jaxb

Comment: Okay tell me first how can i create this question and answers classes.

Comment: Or you go the other way around and create a schema (xsd) that your xml has to conform to. Once you have that you can use tools to create the JAXB classes for you.

Comment: This is very basic Java. Follow the linked tutorial: The BookStore has a name (just as your Question and Answer have a text); it has a list of books (just as your question has a list of answers). Side note: don't give me orders. You're not my boss, and I'm not your slave.

Comment: well I came to know that probably i will not use jAXB so any other options avaiable...

Comment: There are dozens of API to manipulate XML in Java (SAX, DOM, dom4j, JDom, XStream, JAXB, XMLBeans, StAX, commons digester, etc.). Pick one, learn it, and then ask a question if you have a problem.