# How i can store the following in some efficient data structure

Tags: java, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need help in structuring things in XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203211/need-help-in-structuring-things-in-xml-file)

- have a structure like follows:

  ```
  Question0 : What is ur name?
  Answer0: Tina
    Question0.0 : What are your hobbies?
     Answer0.0.0 : reading 
         Question0.0.0.0 :What do you like in reading.?
                Answer0.. : .....
     Answer0.0.1 : Dancing
         Question0.0.0.1 :which dance do you like?
  ...........
  Answer1:Roger 
  ...........same question answer as above.
  ```

Searches: 
   I want to make a datastructure for the above structure which should be able to give me the parent(question) of an answer and also the parent(answer) of a question.can't think of a solution..?

Deletion and addition:
    No need to care about.

A question can have multiple answers. No, every question must have at least one answer. Yes, every question decending from an answer.

Also how I can do this structure numbering very efficiently?

Comment: This seems to be a copy of [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203211/need-help-in-structuring-things-in-xml-file) you submitted. You should create a generic datamodel covering both XML and Java!

Comment: that one was regarding XML...this is about java datastructure...completely different ...might be the same structure string has mislead u...m sorry for that...

Comment: There's a lot of questions that's not answered: is the data fairly static or is it updated\deleted frequently?  Can answers\questions be deleted?  What kinds of searches (if any) do you want to perform?  To choose the right data structure you need to know your requirements.

Comment: @saurabh ranu: I bet this is not different, you should create a logical data (object) model and then derive concrete implementations (XML, java, REST, etc.) based on your requirements. My opinion :-)

Comment: ya May be u r right but I need some directions for how to  create the logical data object model because this looks very complex to me and i am not that well in datastructures...

Comment: Adding to Peter's comment: can a question have multiple answers?  Do some questions have no answer?  Is every question descending from an answer (except for the 1st one)?  If you only have a simple linear sequence of question/answer I would just use a `List<QuestionAndAnswer>`.

Comment: A question can have multiple answers. No, every question must have atleast one answer. Yes, every question decending from an answer. I think its a tree structure and not linear.

Comment: The datastructure is called a tree. Google for how to set that up in Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have followup questions:

```
class Question {
    static final String DEFAULT = "DefaultFollowup";
    String questionText;
    Map<String,Question> responsesAndFollowups;
    Question(String text) {
       this.questionText = text;
       responsesAndFollowups = new HashMap<String,Question>();
    }
    void addFollowup(String response, Question followup) {
        responsesAndFollowups.put(response,followup);
    }
    void setDefaultFollowup(Question followup) {
        addFollowup(DEFAULT,followup);
    }
    Question getFollowup(String response) {
        Question followup = responsesAndFollowups.get(response);
        if(followup == null) followup = responsesAndFollowups.get(DEFAULT);
        return followup;
    }
}
```

Later, you can do this

```
Question name = new Question("What is your name?");
Question hobbies = new Question("What is your favorite hobby?");
Question dancing = new Question("What is your favorite dance?");
Question reading = new Question("What is your favorite book?");

name.setDefaultFollowup(hobbies);
hobbies.setDefaultFollowup(reading); // ask people about reading by default
hobbies.addFollowup("Dancing",dancing); // if they say they like dancing, ask that instead
```

Comment: a question can have multiple answers...

Comment: I mean it a recursive that a question can have only answers as child and it can have as many as possible and a answers can have as many question as it like and so on. The only constraint is that a question should not have a question as direct child and an answer cannot have a answer as direct child.

Comment: this approach would suffice if glowcoder used a MultiMap instead of a HashMap for responsesAndFollowups. Now a single answer could have multiple follup questions. You can find a good Multimap implementation in Google Guava library.

Comment: @Zenzen that's great if you have the ability to pick from among those. And, having a `List<Question>` instead of `Question` would suffice if you didn't want to have an external dependency.

Comment: Yes of course a List<Question> would suffice. I mean a Multimap is just that - a map that can have multiple (ie a list/set/an array) values assigned to a single key!

Comment: @Zenzen Exactly. However, you may not want to include an external dependency if you don't want to. Also, that is a little beyond the scope of this question. It doesn't say anywhere that it needs multiple questions per response. You also would need more background logic to make that determination. In my estimation it's a feature that would be better served in a later release. It wouldn't be in my MMR feature list.

Comment: ya in a response i can have multiple questions again..

Answer (score 0):

Though it is theoretically a part of the Swing framework, the [JTree](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html) class meets pretty much all your requirements.

Comment: sorry i am not using swing.... i am using struts...

Comment: You don't have to use Swing. Just use the JTree class and TreeNode.

Comment: will that be possible?? Can i extract these two classes from swing package

Comment: You are not going to extract them ... just add imports for javax.swing.JTree and javax.swing.Jtree and javax.swing.tree.TreeNode and use them in your code. You might want to read up on JTree package documentation here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/tree/TreeNode.html

Answer (score 0):

Well this is just a simple tree so the very basic implementation would be:

```
public class Question {
   private String question;
   private List<Answer> answers;
   //getters setters adding/removing etc
}

public class Answer {
   private List<Question> questions;
   private String answer;
   //getters setters adding/removing etc
}
```

Then in your code you just need to use a:

```
List<Question> questionsAsked = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

Comment: looks promising.. can u show me some demo....