# How can i parse the following XML using JDOM

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I have an XML document as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<decision>
  <question id="0">
    <questionText>What type is your OS?</questionText>
    <answer id="0">
      <answerText>windows</answerText>
    </answer>
    <answer id="1">
      <answerText>linux</answerText>
    </answer>
    <answer id="2">
      <answerText>mac</answerText>
    </answer>
  </question>
  <question id="1">
    <questionText>What are you looking for?</questionText>
    <answer id="0">
      <answerText>table</answerText>
      <question id="0">
        <questionText>Which color table you want?</questionText>
        <answer id="0">
          <answerText>green</answerText>
        </answer>
        <answer id="1">
          <answerText>black</answerText>
        </answer>
        <answer id="2">
          <answerText>pink</answerText>
        </answer>
      </question>
    </answer>
    <answer id="1">
      <answerText>chair</answerText>
    </answer>
    <answer id="2">
      <answerText>bed</answerText>
    </answer>
    <answer id="3">
      <answerText>cloth</answerText>
    </answer>
  </question>
```

Now I want to parse the above XML using jdom in Java. It kind of recursive and important thing to note is a *Question* can't be a direct child of *Question* and same applies for *Answer*.

Comment: What is the issue that you're facing?

Comment: What do you mean by "parse"? Validate it? Turn it into a Java object tree? Turn it into a XML Document object?

Comment: parse it means just java code to get throught every element and putting it into my object...

Comment: This XML (as you gave it to us) is invalid. You don't close the first nested question, you have a `</answer>` with no opener after the first outer question, and a `</question` with no opener before the last question.

Comment: @oli : I don't know how to parse it recursivley.. :(

Comment: @Wivani: The problem I saw has since been corrected.

Comment: well looks like nobody knows how to parse xml file like this..?

Comment: @saurabh ranu: No, you just haven't been very clear. What is your EXPECTED output from this XML? What happens to the nested questions? Do they become their own entry  into the list or do they become sub-entries?

Comment: @saurabh ranu. The generally accepted meaning of "parsing XML" is to process a character stream and accept the XML grammar productions, which makes it well formed. Additionally, you can validate the parse tree against a DTD or a Schema, which makes it valid. Unfortunately, either of these steps doesn't really tell us anything about the semantics of the structure--which is what you're asking about. You need to be more precise about your "business problem".

Comment: nobody is taking about validation of xml. I am talking about parsing the above xml and create a datastructure out of it.

Answer (score 2):

[Article](http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch14s08.html)

In the light of previous related questions, I'd like to repeat and stress the advice of others (like JB Nizet commented on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7203211/701884)):

**Learn Java, learn XML, pick the tools and API's you need for your project and learn to use those too.** If at one point you get into trouble, everybody here will be happy to help you out debugging your code.

I'm aware that this may seem harsh but it gets to the point where your program gets built by StackOverflow users and not yourself.

That being said, the link at the top of this answer leads to a tutorial on using JDOM to traverse your XML.

Comment: Why u guys don't read the question correctly..the question is not about normal parsing..it's about recursive technique of parsing...

Comment: Why don't you read the article I've mentioned? <quote> _Pay special attention to the listChildren() method. This recursive method is the key to the whole program._ </quote>

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Element.getChildren(String)`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/Element.html#getChildren%28java.lang.String%29) to get all of the question tags and loop through that List - calling `getChildren(String)` to get all of the answers, or [`getChild(String)`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/Element.html#getChild%28java.lang.String%29) if there can be only one child element.

Comment: what about a question within an answers...it has to be somehow recursive...?

Comment: you can use recursion in java, just have another method process sub-questions and call it using tail recursion.

Comment: i posted my approch so far but i really don't know How i can recursively create the data structure and finally get a list of QUESTIONS.?

Comment: create a Class to represent a question, but it will be more difficult if this can be nested infinitely. Pass in your object, have the method update it and pass it back, and keep looping until it doesn't find any more children.

Comment: I already have a class that represent question....Look above. It's a circular dependency

Answer (score 0):

first  that you  need use is XSD to validate the XML.

Comment: Validation is a separate issue.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Validation should be a PRIMARY issue. Invalid XML is (or very well could be) unparseable.

Comment: @josh: Indeed.  But my point was that this is not an answer to the OP's question (or, at best, it's only a partial answer).