# How I can make a efficient data structure consisting of XML contents?

Tags: java, xml, data-structures

I have posted a question here:
[How can i parse the following XML using JDOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231993/how-can-i-parse-the-following-xml-using-jdomry)

I am trying to read the XML posted in the above question so that I can retieve any question or answers just by calling some combination of IDs.

How can I build some of data structures which contains the whole XML, and then how do I make the search for questions or answers more efficient when done on the data structure?

Comment: looking at your post it seems you have basically all you need, i.e. with jdom read all questions, for each question create question object, set the id and question text etc, i'd create a junit test to make sure i can correctly parse with jdom 1 question xml chunk as a first step